# How to echo with PHP this MySQL command

Tags: php, mysql

The following code gives me the following:

```
$getexpenses = "SELECT sum(expense_amount) FROM projects_expense WHERE project_id=$project_id";     
    $showexpenses = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $getexpenses); // Run the query.

    echo ' . $showexpenses . ';
```

Gives me a result of

```
' . $showexpenses . '
```

instead of the actual sum...

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing... thanks!

Comment: btw echoing the result of `mysqli_query()`won't be very useful. You need to treat this with something like `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`;

Comment: Okay - I get the single/double quotes thing... but neither is working? Single quotes prints nothing and double quotes prints . .

Comment: You need to read my comment...

Comment: Sorry , I didn't see you had left a comment. I tried simply replacing the _query with _fetch_assoc but that didn't work

Comment: @user517593 Is your problem now fixed?

Comment: See my answer, you need to query and then fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($showexpenses)`to make it fully functional.
I also sanitized `$project_id` to avoid injections and used an alias to make the sum accessible through an associative array.

```
$getexpenses = "SELECT SUM(`expense_amount`) as `sum_amount` FROM `projects_expense` WHERE `project_id`= ".intval($project_id);     
$showexpenses = mysqli_query ($dbc, $getexpenses);
$sums = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showexpenses);
$sum = $sums['sum_amount'];

echo $sum;
```

We could also have used `mysqli_fetch_row` like this:

```
$getexpenses = "SELECT SUM(`expense_amount`) FROM `projects_expense` WHERE `project_id`= ".intval($project_id);     
$showexpenses = mysqli_query ($dbc, $getexpenses);
$sums = mysqli_fetch_row($showexpenses);
$sum = $sums[0];

echo $sum;
```

The alias is not needed anymore since we know the first column (0) is a match.

NB: you probably also need to `GROUP BY project_id` if you want to use `SUM()`

Answer (score 2):

`echo " . $showexpenses . "` will work for you. You need double quotes, not single.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
   echo $showexpenses;
```

or

```
echo "My query is: {$showexpenses}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Nik's response, PHP treats strings differently based on whether you use Single Quotes or Double Quotes around them.

**Single-Quotes** interpret text as literal text except for '\'' which would output a single quote mark and '\' which would output a slash mark.  For this reason, using single quotes would output your variable name instead of the value.

*Examples:*

```
CODE             | OUTPUT
-----------------+------------------
echo '\t';       | \t
echo '\r';       | \r
echo '$foo';     | $foo
```

**Double-Quotes** interpret certain escape sequences for special characters and also interpret variables.  For instance, "\n" ouputs a linefeed and "\r" outputs a carriage return.  For this reason, echoing "$myvariable" outputs the value instead of the variable name.

*Examples:*

```
CODE             | OUTPUT
-----------------+------------------
echo "\t";       | {tab space}
echo "\r";       | {carriage return}
echo "$foo";     | bar
```

More reading:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php